# Create path without looping through rows of data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

Imagine I have a dataframe that contain information for different persons and there location.

```
Person <- c('A','A','A','B','B','C')
Place  <- c('Ber','Mun','Stu','LA','NY','Ber')

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Person,Place))
```

Now I would like to have a new data frame that tells me how the person traveled. It should look somehow like this:

```
Person From  To
A       Ber   Mun
A       Mun   Stu
B        LA   NY
```

I could do it with by looping over the data frame. But I want to do this for several million rows. Does somebody no a better way?

Best,
Felix

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' , grouped by 'Person', change the 'Place' to 'From' and create the 'To' by taking the 'lead' of 'Place', then remove the rows where there is `NA` in 'To'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,.(From = Place, To =shift(Place, type = 'lead')), Person][!is.na(To)]
#   Person From  To
#1:      A  Ber Mun
#2:      A  Mun Stu
#3:      B   LA  NY
```

---

It can also be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Person) %>%
   transmute(From = Place, To = lead(Place)) %>%
   filter(!is.na(To))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Person [2]
#  Person  From    To
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1      A   Ber   Mun
#2      A   Mun   Stu
#3      B    LA    NY
```

Comment: Great, I knew there was a much better way! I tried to vote you up, but apparently my reputation below is 15. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I put two subsets of the df side by side, one without the head, one without the tail, and then I keep the result only if the person is the same on each side:

```
library(magrittr)
df2 <- df[-nrow(df),] %>%
  cbind(df[-1,]) %>%
  setNames(c("Person","From","Person2","To")) %>%
  subset(Person == Person2) %>%
  '['(,-3)

#   Person From  To
# 1      A  Ber Mun
# 2      A  Mun Stu
# 4      B   LA  NY
```